# Detect an app on home screen of iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-web-app, homescreen, iphone-standalone-web-app

You know how its possible to add a web app to the home screen of an iPhone... well now how do i detect if my app has been added to the home screen of a user's iPhone.

And if it has been added, how do i launch the app stored on the user's home screen rather than in Safari.

`NOTE : its a web app simply bookmarked on the home screen of an iPhone - it is NOT a native app.`

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I don't get it. Web apps only run in Safari.

Comment: yes you are right, but i want it to run in full screen without the header address bar and the footer icons which are default in safari. is that possible ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [Safari Web Content Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html), you have to set `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />` in your webpage to present your content in full-screen mode.

You can also set a startup image to make it look like a native app by setting `<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/startup.png">`

**Edit (Detect if run in full-screen mode)**

You can add some JS-Code to your webpage to detect if it is run in full-screen mode:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('standalone' in navigator && !navigator.standalone && (/iphone|ipod|ipad/gi).test(navigator.platform) && (/Safari/i).test(navigator.appVersion)) {
    __do something here__
}
```

For more information on this, [this project](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen) could be of interest.

Comment: ok .. this works well if the app is added to the home screen .. but not in Safari. The question actually is - if there is a way to detect if an app has been added to the home screen and if it can be opened if someone visits a URL

Comment: Hi! yes this helps .. to detect if the webpage has been added to homescreen or not! thanks a ton.

I think i can work around this.